# Marshaling a double list and class cast exception

Tags: java, list, jaxb, marshalling

I want to write a code in java that the result of marshaling would be like this:

```
<pointset>
//defining a point with x, y, and z values
<point>
  <XYZ> 1.0 2.5 4.6> </XYZ>
</point>
<point>
//defining a point with x, y, and z values
  <XYZ> 0.0 3.6 8.6> </XYZ>
</point>
</pointset>
```

XYZ element is a list of double values. Is this possible?

P.S. I use JAXB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that the easiest way to do this is to create the XML Schema for the XML file, and then generate the Java classes from the Schema.

Your schema (`myxml.xsd`) would be:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsd:element name="pointset" type="PointSet" />

  <xsd:complexType name="PointSet" final="extension restriction">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="point" type="Point" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="Point" final="extension restriction">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="XYZ" type="XYZ" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="XYZ">
    <xsd:list itemType="xsd:double" />
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Use the `xjc` command that comes with Java to generate the classes.

```
xjc myxml.xsd -p myxml
```